# cannot read "this" in react native function

Tags: react-native, this, facebook-login, fbsdk

I am trying to set the user data from facebook login and store it in a state but there is an error occurred.

**Facebook Authentication**

```
_fbAuth(){
  LoginManager.logInWithReadPermissions(['public_profile']).then(function(res){
    if(res.isCancelled){
      console.log('login cancelled.')
    } else {
      AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken().then(tokenData => {
        if(tokenData) {
          const { accessToken, userID } = tokenData;
          fetch('https://graph.facebook.com/v2.5/me?fields=email,name,friends&access_token=' + accessToken).then((response) => 
            response.json()).then((json) => {
              this.setState({ user_email: json.email })
            }).catch(() => {
              reject('ERROR GETTING DATA FROM FACEBOOK')
            }
          )
        }
      })
    }
  }, function(err){
    console.log(err)
  })
}
```

Registering the data into a state throwing this error :

> [TypeError: undefined is not a function (evaluating '_this3.setState({
>   user_email: json.email })')]

How should I access `this` inside the `fetch()` response?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is due to the fact that `this` has gotten lost due to the nested arrow functions. You define a variable to hold a reference to `this` and use `that` instead.

You can solve it by doing the following inside your function

```
_fbAuth = () => {
  const that = this;
  ...
  that.setState({ user_email: json.emal });
  ...
}
```

You should also make sure that you have bound your function by either making it an arrow function, or by binding it in the constructor.

Answer (score 1):

Add this line in your constructor to bind the component context to function scope.

```
this._fbAuth = this._fbAuth.bind(this);
```

This should work!

Answer (score 1):

Don´t use `bind` or the old `const that = this` workaround. This is much easier if you just switch to arrow functions completely, and i would suggest using async/await too. For example:

```
_fbAuth = async () => {
    try {
        let resLogin = await LoginManager.logInWithReadPermissions(['public_profile', 'email', 'user_friends']);
        if(resLogin.isCancelled){
            console.log('login cancelled.');
            return;
        }
        let resTokenData = await AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken();
        if(resTokenData) {
            const {accessToken, userID} = resTokenData;
            let resAPI = await fetch(`https://graph.facebook.com/v2.5/me?fields=email,name,friends&access_token=${accessToken}`);
            resAPI = resAPI.json();
            this.setState({user_email: resAPI.email});
        }
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
};
```

Avoid the "callback hell", it looks a lot cleaner and easier to read with async/await. Should work with the LoginManager, as it seems to return a Promise. I have also added template strings to the example and added a return when the user cancelled. There is no need to indent the whole `else` block that way.

Btw, you are trying to get email and friends with the API, but you are not asking for the permissions, is that intentional? I have added the permissions anyway.

Comment: Thank you for the details explanation. It's my first time with the fb integration on app so I just copy others code and try it out. Btw up vote for pointing it out. :)

Comment: you are welcome! a tip: don´t just copy/paste code, make sure you understand every single line :)

Answer (score 0):

```
_fbAuth(){

const _this = this;  // add this line

  LoginManager.logInWithReadPermissions(['public_profile']).then(function(res){
    if(res.isCancelled){
      console.log('login cancelled.')
    } else {
      AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken().then(tokenData => {
        if(tokenData) {
          const { accessToken, userID } = tokenData;
          fetch('https://graph.facebook.com/v2.5/me?fields=email,name,friends&access_token=' + accessToken).then((response) => 
            response.json()).then((json) => {
              _this .setState({ user_email: json.email }) // replace this with _this
            }).catch(() => {
              reject('ERROR GETTING DATA FROM FACEBOOK')
            }
          )
        }
      })
    }
  }, function(err){
    console.log(err)
  })
}
```